# How to push and pop tasks of the queue in celery

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery

I want to save large amount of images to the image server. I need to queue all requests of images information for saving them using Celery.I use Django framework. 
I read the document of Celery and configured it in Django and,I also created a queue under the name "images", but I don't know how to put information of images to the queue and send message for saving and remove them from the queue after saving. 
I couldn't find any command for push and pop tasks in queue in the document of Celery.

Here is the code of how I configured the celery:

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue
from celery import Celery
import os

class CeleryQueue:

   def celery_queue(self):

       os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DataScience.settings')
       app = Celery('images', broker='amqp://localhost')
       app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
       app.autodiscover_tasks()
       image_exchange = Exchange('media', type='direct')
       app.conf.task_default_queue = 'images'
       app.conf.task_default_exchange_type = 'direct'
       app.conf.task_default_routing_key = 'media.image'
       app.conf.task_queues = (Queue('images', image_exchange,routing_key=app.conf.task_default_routing_key))
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused reading the documentation. The queue is used to store tasks. Tasks are written as functions and decorated with @task. So when you call a task use task_name.delay(parameters)